# Query filter (ArcGIS Pro) on SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, arcgis

At the moment i'm trying to upgrade our old query filter on an oracle database to a SQL server. The old query is as follows:

```
select * from table.a a, table.b b WHERE sdo_relate(a.shape, b.shape, 'mask=anyinteract')='TRUE'
```

Now I can find myself that the sdo_relate is not a function for SQL server. From the internet I can tell that I need to use ST_Relate. However I cant find the right way to query this.

The answer I want:
I would like to have the exact same query, where in all the vector feature from table a within the boundary of geometry b (polygon) get selected or clipped.

Special thing:
There is one additional problem. Whereas table B was dedicated to the geometry(polygon) of the boundary I needed. However this is changed into multiple boundary's so now I need a special layer (selection) within table B.

Is there anyone that can help me and please as well explain how to build this SQL filter on a SQLserver.

The query filter is used within  ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: Does Oracle *not* support ANSI-92 explicit JOIN syntax or something..? Why hasn't it adopted it yet; it's been around for over *30 years*.

Comment: @ThomA For some strange reason, comma-joins are ver popular with Oracle coders. Maybe the docs are using the old syntax or something?

Comment: i think it sounds like you want STWithin, which returns if whole geometry "fits" inside another one, but who knows, i dont' speak oracalease, you might have better luck if you draw a picture of what you want to find. The sql server syntax is: `select 1 WHERE GEOMETRY::Point(10,10, 4326).STWithin(GEOMETRY::Point(10,10, 4326)) = 1`

Answer (score 1):

You just do `someGeometryColumn.STRelate(otherColumn, ...`. I'm not sure the mask syntax, it uses DE9IM and I don't know how that relates to what you want.

```sql
select *
from tablea a
join tableb b on a.shape.STRelate(b.shape, 'Some DE9IM pattern here') = 1;
```